My fund is showing on dex but not in my wallet
Good morning to you,It’s been months since I used the Kamino protocol through the phantom app,I deposited Sol to Kamino,and I borrowed usdc against it,but I don’t seems to see the usdc reflected in my phantom wallet,but whenever I connect my wallet to Jupiter dex, it reflects the usdc but the swapping don’t seems to work. It keeps telling me amount not found in the wallet,but it reflects on the balance whenever I connect my wallet to any dex.  Why?
This is my public wallet: 6BTuPfCp3q9dqMnr8F8ixoVUXUpSxgPJmEhF5wvszDAK
This is the txn:  https://solscan.io/tx/4oLaRud5i3GAWZrAR9WX84Ekai5qteTBf1NtTwkLB7gvWFgoYML2a2RDRNhWeC4hXEEtRhY4XhHn4HHKhpLBis6q

I’m voting to close this question because this site is for dev q&a, not wallet support

In the tx you shared USDC is sent to address 8hFAuFH8DZrGf1nJnH8wd1ysRkpFfsCpwJwHswRV8kKS which is different from the wallet address you shared in the post.
Are you sure you're connecting the right wallet to the platform?
Meanwhile, please try adding the USDC token manually in Phantom Wallet.
